# edit action in tableview without Edit button?

Tags: iphone

i want to show all rows in my tableview(when it loads) with red mark (negative symbol) in `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask`. In other words if i click red mark ,it must show delete button for that particular row (edit button's action will be taken without pressing edit button) in table view. The following code is giving a run time error and It is not showing the minus red mark as well for each row?

I want to do it without an Edit button so what i need to do to achieve it?

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0], nil]; 

[tableView beginUpdates];

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 

[tv endUpdates];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what exactly you are trying to do. But if you want to enter edit mode (the same what would happen if the user presses the "edit" button) you simply have to call:

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]
```

For more information see UITableView documentation.