# how to delete row in table view without Edit Button?

Tags: iphone

I want to show all rows in my tableview (when it loads) with a red mark (minus sign) in `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask`. In other words if I click the red mark, it should show a delete button for that particular row. (The edit button's action will be taken without pressing the edit button) in the table view.  The following code gives a run time error. and also it did not show the red minus sign in each row.  What do I have to do? (I want to do this without requiring an edit button.)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0], nil]; 
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Why not put the `UITableView` in edit mode and just disallow reordering?  Then you don't need an edit button.

Comment: hi, i am a student. i want clear explaination

Comment: -1: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502749/edit-action-in-tableview-without-edit-button

Answer (score 1):

[Check the `UITableView` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/setEditing:animated:):

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: That line of code is all you should need. This puts your table view into editing mode. This is explained in the documentation.

Comment: i am confusing , what i have to do? to add your code to my code

Comment: You need to read the documentation, I think. But you just add that line to your view controller, where you initialize your view.